# Reading plist many times vs. Creating object and read plist only once to access data in plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I would like to make a data manager class that retrieves data from plist, and I wonder if I should make a class with all class methods which read plist every time when the method is called and returns requested value, or create a class initializer which initializes an array(instance variable) with the plist data and all methods are instance methods which get data from the array.

I would like to know which is more expensive:reading plist many times (like 50 times) or instantiating an object, or simply which is better.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: “Reading NSBundle” doesn't make sense. Do you mean reading the plist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the classical tradeoffs in programming - speed vs. memory use. The technique of reading something once and storing it on a faster medium (in this example, in memory) is called caching. It's very popular, and for good reason. Mass storage devices are still magnitudes slower than RAM, and network access is magnitudes slower than local mass storage.

If you assume the data will be asked of the manager often, and if you assume the plist won't change (or you can detect changes), then read the plist on the first access to the getter, store it in an iVar, and answer only the iVar as long as the plist hasn't changed. This uses a little more memory, but is a lot faster for subsequent accesses.

NOTE: This approach would be harmful for very, very large files. If you are concerned about memory usage, implement the `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` method in your viewControllers, and flush the cache (delete it) when you are low on memory.

A getter method could look like this:

```
- (NSArray *)data
{
    if (!cacheArray) {
        //what we do now is called "lazy initialization": we initialize our array only when we first need the data.
        //This is elegant, because it ensures the data will always be there when you ask for it,
        //but we don't need to initialize for data that might never be needed, and we automatically re-fill the array in case it has been deleted (for instance because of low memory)
        cacheArray = ... //read array from plist here; be sure to retain or copy it
    }
    return cacheArray;
}
```

Comment: @Peter Hosey Thanks for the edit. I don't really get what you mean by "corrected implementation of method", though. Have I overlooked a problem with my original implementation?

Comment: My best guess is that @Peter has a thing for only having a single point of return.  Plus, you neglected to return the array after allocating it otherwise.

Comment: I don't care about single point of return (I actually have no problem using early return), though I tend to prefer it when multiple returns don't improve anything. My only problem was the missing return at the end. I took the opportunity to fix that, simplify via single-return, and add the note about retaining in one edit.

Comment: Oh, right, that final return. Yes, I did verily forget that. Shame on me! Still, I like early returns, because they make it very clear to the reader under what circumstances a method is not going to be executed any further.

Comment: @fzwo You're welcome on all counts—from all of us, on the last one.

Comment: @Peter Hosey Thank you for your help. I'm still not sure about your answer. Did you mean I should create manager class with instance method -(NSArray *)data and instance variable (NSArray *)casheArray?

Comment: @kazuhito0000 Yes, that is the idea. Create an instance variable `NSArray *cacheArray`. Access that cacheArray through the getter method that does the lazy initialization, like above. When the method is run the first time, it will detect that there is no cache array, and read the XML file to create it. When it is run the second time, it will find the cache array and return it (instead of reading the XML again, which is a lot slower).

Comment: @Peter Hosey How about making init method which initializes the cacheArray when the object is instantiated?

Comment: @kazuhito0000 (You do realize that I am not Peter, and that I posted the answer, yes?) That would also be very possible. It would make initialization take slightly longer, but make the first call as fast as subsequent calls. This would be called *greedy* or *eager initialization*.

Comment: @fzwo I realized now, sorry about that. Thank you fzwo for your help.